# How to pull a value in between multiple values?

Tags: sql, oracle, erp

I have a column named Concatenated Segments which has 12 segment values, and I'm looking to edit the formula on the column to only show the 5th segment. The segments are separated by periods.

[image: Screenshot of the column value]

How would I need to edit the formula to do this?

[image: Picture of edit formula area]

Would using a substring work?

Comment: This looks like OBIEE/OBIA. In the Accounting folder of the Procurement subject area, you should see the segments broken out.

Comment: This really looks like OBIEE and the functions accessible in OBIEE are associated with Logical SQL, https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/e10545/sql_bi_view_object.htm#BIEDV1041.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, using good old `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` combination

- possibly *faster* on large data sets
- which doesn't care about uninterrupted strings (can contain anything between dots)

---

```
SQL> WITH
  2    -- thank you for typing, @marcothesane
  3  indata(s) AS (
  4    SELECT '1201.0000.5611005.0099.211003.0000.2199.00099.00099.0000.0000.00000' FROM dual
  5  )
  6  select substr(s, instr(s, '.', 1, 4) + 1,
  7                   instr(s, '.', 1, 5) - instr(s, '.', 1, 4) - 1
  8               ) result
  9  from indata;

RESULT
------
211003

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR()`, searching for the 5th uninterrupted string of digits, or the 5th uninterrupted string of anything but a dot (`\d` and `[^\.]`) starting from position 1 of the input string:

```
WITH
-- your input ... paste it as text next time, so I don't have to manually re-type it ....
indata(s) AS (
  SELECT '1201.0000.5611005.0099.211003.0000.2199.00099.00099.0000.0000.00000' FROM dual
)
SELECT
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(s,'\d+',1,5)    AS just_digits
, REGEXP_SUBSTR(s,'[^\.]+',1,5) AS between_dots
FROM indata;
-- out  just_digits | between_dots 
-- out -------------+--------------
-- out  211003      | 211003
```